# EditText Property in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
    <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/eduserId"
    android:hint="User ID"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
```

IN android , can any one tell me what the line is called that you see in EditText and can we change its color?? how ??
I m wiiling to change the color of the EditText Line.

Comment: Do you want to change the color of your text ???

Comment: None of the above line will call, because .xml is static designing of Activity.

Comment: Which line want to change you??

Comment: line that appears below the text , m not asking about border or its color. this is just a line that apear below the text when there is some test in the EditText

Comment: i dont know the name of that property , the property i have given above does not require any help.. i dont wana change the text color.

Comment: The line which is display as a blue color it is the current focus on EditText@Deepti

Answer (score 1):

Use following property in Edit text.

```
 <android:textColor="#colorcode" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply Background to your `EditText` -

```
 android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
```

Here is `edit_text_border.xml` :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#1473bb" />

    </shape>
```

Comment: m not asking about border color. m using the default edittext look, but want to change the color of that line(dont know what it is called) that apear below the text ,if there is text in EditText,

Comment: @Deepti - The text in EditText is without the lines below it. It is not underlined, there is no border or it is not different then just a simple text unless you do so.

Comment: you can change the color of blinking cursor ... but for line no Idea

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the color of the text cursor. This is the property you need to use:

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@color/my_cursor_color"
```

And add in the file res/values/colors.xml

```
<color name="my_cursor_color">#color_code</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1. Use Android assets studios Android Holo colors generator to generate
   the resources, styles and themes you need to add to your app to get
   the holo look across all devices.
2. Use holo everywhere library.
3. Use the PNG for the holo text fields and set them as background
   images yourself. You can get the images from the Android assets
   studios holo color generator. You'll have to make a drawable and
   define the normal, selected and disabled states.

Create your own line in Photoshop for example and then make the background image of your edit text this line.

```
android:background="@drawable/my_line"
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a `9-patch` image with holo theme and set as background.